# input2 as length, input1 are in the range [1, n] and each integer appears once/ twice, return arrqy of integers that appears twice

Tags: python, python-3.2

```
class UserMainCode(object):

    @classmethod
    def range(cls, input1, input2):
        pass
```

Example:

- input1: (1,1,2)
- input2: 3
- Output: {1}

Answer (score -1):

The following code below would do the trick. It uses the [`collections .Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count all items in the list/tuple. The code also uses the new [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) from Python 3 to enable static analysis.

```py
from collections import Counter


class UserMainCode:
    @classmethod
    def range(cls, input1: list[int], input2: int) -> list[int]:
        input = input1[0:input2 + 1]
        counter = Counter(input)
        return [
            x for x, count in counter.items()
            if count == 2
        ]


print(UserMainCode.range((1, 1, 2, 3, 3), 5))
# Prints: [1, 3]
```

It's also possible to eliminate `input2` entirely as lists/tuples/dicts... have the length read by the function [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)